# Git in Netbeans -> Clone and Push?

Tags: git, netbeans

I am using Netbeans 7 with Windows 7 and I just can't figure out, how I can clone a project from my private repo, make a new Zend Project and push it back.
The first steps are no problem, I am able clone the repository and make a new Zend project, but how can I push it back ?! The only thing I can do is initialize a new empty repository based on my created code. But if I push it, it isn't in my server repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The git plugin has to be installed first (Tools->Plugins and search for git), then you should be able to find git related command under :

> Team -> Git

menu .

Answer (score 0):

The same menu is available when right-clicking on the project name in the project panel.